# Cropping an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

when I embed the below map on my website it comes with a horrible black bar at the top with various options. Is there anyway of cropping the iframe to just show the map and not the black bar?

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1S9wPj5PsIDClLqPEiHWqtpNpm1mJECA&ehbc=2E312F" width="845" height="684"></iframe>
```

if it is possible, i want to maintain 845x684 but with no black bar

any suggestions?

tried various different bits of html from existing stackoverflow questions, but none worked

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to wrap your iframe in a `div` of the same dimensions, then use CSS to vertically offset the `iframe` within. For example:

```
  <div style="width: 845px; height: 684px; overflow: hidden;">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1S9wPj5PsIDClLqPEiHWqtpNpm1mJECA&amp;ehbc=2E312F" width="845" height="684" style="position: relative; top: -70px;"></iframe> 
    </div>
```

The `overflow` property on the outer `div` ensures the offset content is not visible. The `-70px` offset can be adjusted to whatever else you'd prefer.